# Image div + text on hover

Tags: image, hover, overlay

Hey guys Im just wondering how to do a hover on image and fade the image a colour with opacity 0.5. also with centered text.  I know a bit how to do it I'm just not sure if its purely css possible or jquery is required? Thanks guys for help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/YgMLn/4/

```
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/o7iAFMu.jpg" width="100px" class="test"/>

.test:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Where do you want the text to go?

Edit in response to comment:

I think then you need to wrap the image in a container div.

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="image.png"/>
</div>

#container:hover {
    background: yellow;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

If you want the image centered you can apply text-align:center to the container div or if you  want text overlaid on top of the image centered I would suggest then making the image a background of the container div. Let me know exactly what you want... Post a sample if you can or create a fiddle. thanks.

Edit in response to comment.

Please see if this would work: http://jsfiddle.net/L8xhA/4/

Comment: I want it in the middle.  Oh and I wanted it to highlight with a colour with 0.5 opacity not just turn down the image.

Comment: Just the text to be centered thats all. Something similar to this, hover over it has like a black look with some text in the middle that fades in. http://codepen.io/ansac/details/BHtkE

Comment: Something like that yeah thanks.  I'm trying to get it to ease out smooth too and the text not to drop opacity. Nesting it above the overlay doesnt help to keep the opacity after having it at 1.0.